# I can not upload my apk to play store because of the key problem. I always use same sign key

Tags: android, google-play, apk, android-app-bundle, app-bundle

I uploaded my application with the same sign key for 4 years.
But last week I wanted to convert apk to aab and I selected aab(app bundle format)
And then I don't use my sign key, I tried to upload and I saw:
"You uploaded an APK that is not signed with the upload certificate. You must use the same certificate. The upload certificate has fingerprint:
SHA1: 2C:6A:........
and the certificate used to sign the APK that you uploaded has fingerprint:
SHA1: B5:40:.........."

Anymore I can not upload either apk not aab because of this key problem.

How can solve this issue?

Comment: "How can solve this issue?" By signing the apk with the upload key.

Comment: you have to generate signed bundle using existing signing configs which you were using while creating apk.

Comment: I did it, but google play did not accept this sign.

Comment: Contact Google Play support for them to reset the key